# Zurb foundation table stripe styling

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I do not want to the default stripe styling for alternating rows in the Zurb Foundation css framework.

What's the easiest way to remove it?

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tables.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can overwrite the foundation table alternating CSS rule using:

```
table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: That is one fine piece of working explanation! Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good solution, since it overrides the existing CSS and also uses an `!important` which is always a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could go the more semantic route and use mixins.  Something like:

```
$table-bg: #fff;
$table-even-row-bg: #fff;
```

Should work.

Answer (score 2):

For [Foundation 6.4](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/table.html#stripes):

> By default, table rows are striped. There's an `.unstriped` class to remove the stripes. If you change `$table-is-striped` to false to remove stripes from all tables, use the `.striped` class to add stripes.

So this is now something you can configure, or disable and enable selectively on tables.

For previous versions of Foundation 6, you may have to add the following to your `settings` or as a last resort, to your main CSS file:

```
$table-striped-background: $table-background;
```

This assumes that you `@import` your Foundation library instead of including the compiled version as a dumb CSS file in your page. The real advantage of a SCSS framework like Foundation is that it's written in SCSS so you can extend and use it in your SCSS.

Comment: This should be near the top. Accepted solution with !important used makes me queezy.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the link you provided and it looks like all you'll have to do is remove this segment in the css:

```
table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the process of integrating the ZURB stack into my workflow and I needed some tables striped and some non-striped. I'm working with table classes that I can't modify on the backend, but with SASS, I was able to remove stripes like this:

```
.table-special{
  @extend: .unstriped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `_settings.scss` either:

```
$table-color-scale:0%
```

or

```
$table-is-striped: false;
```